# How do i convert IgniteCache to JSON?

Tags: json, ignite

I want to convert the value in IgniteCache to JSON
As an example, I would appreciate it.

```
ex)
CacheConfiguration<String, String> cache = new CacheConfigruation<>();
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start();
IgniteCache<String, String> igniteCache = 
ignite.getOrCreateCache(cache);
igniteCache.put("key1","value");
igniteCache.put("key2","value");
```

How do I convert to json?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 2):

```
CacheConfiguration<String, JSONObject> cache = new CacheConfigruation<>();
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start();
IgniteCache<String, JSONObject> igniteCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cache);
igniteCache.put("key1","value");
igniteCache.put("key2","value");
```

Comment: Why do you think that key always should be in string?

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. it is not mandatory that key should be string ,  Thank you for recognizing above error, I will update that.

Comment: Can a Value be little more complex? (e.g. nested array instead of a String)

Comment: yes, you can insert any value as it support any object type in value  (Eg. IgniteCache<String, Object> igniteCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cache);                igniteCache.put("key", Object)  ;)

Comment: Can that Object be multi-dimensional JSON object? (or need to be 1-dimension?) How does Ignite map multi-dimensions?

Comment: Yes, you can use JSONObject inside JSONObject (nested) . Ignite considers whole object as a single entity.

Comment: Do you maybe have an example (or point me in some direction) regarding JSONObject inside JSONObject - how to create it and store it in Ignite? Can Index be added to any field of nested objects and query it on that field (e.g. Filter or Agregate queries)? (if you have example - that would be really great)..

Answer (score 1):

Ignite is key-value cache with bunch of other feature like SQL, but first of all it is cache, you can save JSON to cache or any other stuff. You can use a lib like gson to convert object to json and then save it to ignite, there's an example for you: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Primitives-Examples

Answer (score 1):

```
CacheConfiguration<String, JSONObject> cache = new CacheConfigruation<>();
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start();
IgniteCache<String, JSONObject> igniteCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cache);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("key1",value);
igniteCache.put("key",new JSONObject().put("key2",json));
```

here in above code I have added JSONObject inside other JSONObject and stored it in Cache on key as "key" if you have to extract above JSONObject you will get following ans.

```
JSONObject output = igniteCache.get("key");

output : {
           key2 : 
                { 
                  key1 : value 
                }
          }
```

For Indexing please check this link : https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain-advanced-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/gridgain/examples/datagrid/query/SqlQueryExample.java